# How to get "cuisine" (food type) for a restaurant using Google Places API and/or Google Business API

Tags: google-places-api, google-business, google-business-profile-api

I am getting some Restaurant information using the nearBy function of Google Places. It returns the Restaurant... rating... address, etc. But I can't find the "cuisine" of that restaurant in the returned information for found places.
How can I find it so I can show the user what type of food they can get in the restaurant. By "cuisine" I mean... Italian, Local, Chinese, Sushi, ...
I think I need to use a second API, probably Google Business API, but I can't find how.

Comment: I don't think this is currently available in the API. But there's a popular feature request regarding more detailed place types for the Places API here:  https://issuetracker.google.com/35822953. You can star the issue to get notified by it if there's an update.